# C: Pointers/arrays manipulation

Tags: c, pointers

when i run the following code i don't get any issues

```
int main(){
    char charr[] = "hallo you my name is :  \0";

    char *charName = "name \0";

    mystrcat(charr,charName);
}

void mystrcat(char *s,char *t) {
    while(*s!='\0')
        s++;
    s--;                      /* goes back to \0 char */
    while((*s=*t)!='\0')
    {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}
```

but when running the following code which does the same thing 
i get   "Dumping stack trace to file.exe.stackdump"  error

```
int main(){
    char *charr = "hallo you my name is :  \0";

    char *charName = "name \0";

    mystrcat(charr,charName);
}

void mystrcat(char *s,char *t) {
    while(*s!='\0')
        s++;
    s--;                      /* goes back to \0 char */
    while((*s=*t)!='\0')
    {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}
```

can anyone give me an explanation on why this happening?

Comment: Remove the `\0` in the second code listing when specifying string literals, it isn't needed.

Comment: still does not solve the issue

Comment: Undefined behavior to modify a string literal.

Comment: everything is the same in both codes except that in the first one "charr" is of type Pointer, and in the second code is't an array

Comment: Not relative but you don't check empty string for `s` so you can write on out bounded memory, and you are not checking if your are not going after `s`

Comment: You should overwrite the first `\0`. The second one will be automatically assigned due to the assignment in the `while` loop.